# Is it any easy way to create a form at center of the page (horizontally and vertically) in semantic-ui-react?

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have tried some workaround like making height 100%. But i want to know is there any alternative provide by semantic-ui-react.

Answer (score 0):

The SUI example you are referencing has some custom styles being used to make that work. You can see those styles inline in the `<head>` tag.

```
body {
  background-color: #DADADA;
}
body > .grid {
  height: 100%;
}
.image {
  margin-top: -100px;
}
.column {
  max-width: 450px;
}
```

Semantic UI React has all of the exact same layouts implemented there as well under "[Layouts](https://react.semantic-ui.com/layouts)". You can see the [login example you reference here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/layouts/login). The [source for that layout can be seen here](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/docs/app/Layouts/LoginLayout.js). There are notes in the source that point out some of the specifics in the CSS needed to make that work other than simply setting the `Grid` component like this:

```
<Grid
  textAlign='center'
  style={{ height: '100%' }}
  verticalAlign='middle'
>
```

You also need to set the parent containers to a height of 100%. This is true any time you are trying to utilize the viewport height of the window. All parent containers up to the `<body>` must have their height defined:

```
<style>
  body > div,
  body > div > div,
  body > div > div > div.login-form {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Obviously for your project you would not want to throw a style tag like this in the middle of a component on your page the way the example does.